# Can I have SSIS solutions that point to different file locations for the dtsx files

Tags: ssis, development-environment

The problem is that I want SSIS packages in one folder and many solutions NOT in the folder. Right now if i add an existing package it copies the package to the solution folder. is there a way around this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know you'd rather people just answer questions here, but could help me understand the problem you hope to overcome by having a project with distributed packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your packages in your solution/project folder, choose to deploy them to the path where you want your packages to be run from.

Comment: Yes, this is the best choice. I 'COULD' use symbolic links, but that would get dicey.